# laravel model constant into controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model that contains a constant but I want it to move in my controller because the amounts for each key (Basic,Junior,Premium,Advanced,Senior) are being calculated and not fixed. I think moving it inside a controller function I can easily update the amount for each key.

User Model:

```
protected const AMOUNTS = [
   'Basic' => 0,
   'Junior' => 100,
   'Premium' => 150,
   'Advanced' => 200,
   'Senior' => 250,
];
```

and I'm accessing those constants in a function like this

```
protected function get_amount($rank)
{
    $amount = self::AMOUNTS[$rank];
}
```

I literally don't know how to convert it to fit inside the controller because I want to move in controller because the amount is dynamic and not fixed.

I want something like in my controller

```
// Controller
public function insert()
{
    // Setting the amount for each
    $amounts = [
       'Basic' => $basic_amount,
       'Junior' => $junior_amount,
       'Premium' => $premium_amount,
       'Advanced' => $advanced_amount,
       'Senior' => $senior_amount,
    ];

    // The problem is how to access that, if that's the case?
    // I can't do the same with the model using self::AMOUNTS[$rank];
}
```

Comment: So you want to keep the AMOUNTS constant inside the model, and use it from the controller?

Comment: no, I will change the amount, because something is happened that is not included in the question, the amount is calculating, and will set the value after calculation, that's why I want to move it to controller to change the value dynamically

Answer (score 3):

Constants values cant be modified once set, thats the purpose of them, however you can change it into a static array in your controller, and you can change its values when you want :

```
// Controller
// Controller
protected static $amounts = [
    'Basic' => 0,
    'Junior' => 100,
    'Premium' => 150,
    'Advanced' => 200,
    'Senior' => 250,
];

public function insert()
{
    // Setting the amount for each
    self::$amounts = [
       'Basic' => $basic_amount,
       'Junior' => $junior_amount,
       'Premium' => $premium_amount,
       'Advanced' => $advanced_amount,
       'Senior' => $senior_amount,
    ];

}
```

and to read a value you can simply do  `self::$amounts['Junior']` and it will get you the value

Comment: `self::$amount['Junior']` should be `self::$amounts['Junior']`

Comment: Hello, I'm trying it now in the model. I'm getting error in `protected static` syntax error

Comment: @kerbh0lz, correct sorry for the typo.
OP, you are not making it clear, you said you wanted to move it out of the model to the controller

Answer (score -1):

laravel controller is a normal php `class` witch extends a `BaseController::class`

and const is a php feature

ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php you can read this

so how you will use this in controller is

```
<?php
class MyClass
{

    const AMOUNTS = [
        'Basic' => 0,
        'Junior' => 100,
        'Premium' => 150,
        'Advanced' => 200,
        'Senior' => 250,
    ];


    public function insert()
    {
        $amounts = self::AMOUNTS;
    }
}
```

---

and you don't need to move in to controller just create const like this in model

```php
<?php
class ModelClass
{

    const AMOUNTS = [
        'Basic' => 0,
        'Junior' => 100,
        'Premium' => 150,
        'Advanced' => 200,
        'Senior' => 250,
    ];
}
```

then in contsoller you can get the data by

```php
public function insert()
{
     ModelClass::AMOUNTS['Basic'];
     $amounts = ModelClass::AMOUNTS; // to get all
}
```